# Situacion con Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

He tratado de instalar y usar el Visual Studio 2017 RC sin éxito. Estoy tratando de crear aplicaciones cross platform.

Estos videos demuestran los pasos que seguí para instalar en VS 2017 RC. Antes que nada ya reinstalé Windows 10 y traté todo esto en una instalación nueva en una máquina virtual. En las dos ocasiones ocurrieron los mismos problemas. Así que esto descarta un posible Windows dañado.

Setup:

1. lo que seleccioné para instalar: http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=wkl2yr%3E&s=9#.WGk2Imravcv
2. Termino sin errores, pero http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=30x7qcm%3E&s=9#.WGk3wWravcs
3. el SDK no quedó instalado, aunque la instalación dijo que sí http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=vewv7m%3E&s=9#.WGk53Wravcs Tuve que instalarlo a mano como administrador aunque el api 23 nunca se instaló como reportó la instalación. Además, no sé si seleccioné todo lo necesario, por eso pongo los pasos seguidos por si esto crea otros problemas.
4. Después de corregir el SDK, ahora dice que el problema es el java versión http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2vaz7rl%3E&s=9#.WGlAC2ravcs Instalé la nueva versión correctamente.
5. Pero ahora salen errores de referencias dañadas y un error de IDE que antes no ocurría http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=mil8b7%3E&s=9#.WGlGQ2ravcs

Éste es el error:

> (IDE ERROR 006:
>
> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error Error finding Android/Java SDKs System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r13b\prebuilt\windows\bin\toolchains'. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator1.CommonInit()
>      at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(String path, String searchPattern) at Xamarin.Android.Build.Utilities.AndroidSdkBase.Initialize(String androidSdkPath, String androidNdkPath, String javaSdkPath) at Xamarin.Android.Build.Utilities.AndroidSdk.Refresh(String androidSdkPath, String androidNdkPath, String javaSdkPath) App1.Droid)

Sólo me falta resolver las referencias dañadas y el error del IDE 0006.

¿Cuál es el motivo del error?

Comment: Al parecer no tienes hubicada la ruta de tu NDK

Comment: verifica en tus herramientas->opciones->xamarin-android, ahi deberia de estar con palomita las tres opciones que son el SDK, el JDK y el NDK